# How to accelerate OpenCvSharp3 with Cuda?

Tags: c#, opencv

How do you enable CUDA acceleration with OpenCvSharp3? Documentation is non-existant. Do I have to install some prebuilt OpenCV CUDA libraries? Do I have to modify my code to use CUDA acceleration?

```
var input = new OpenCvSharp.Mat(filename, OpenCvSharp.ImreadModes.GrayScale);
var output = input.EmptyClone();
OpenCvSharp.Cv2.Sobel(input, output, OpenCvSharp.MatType.CV_8U, 1, 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They removed the support in the latest version of OpenCvSharp3

`OpenCvSharp does not support CUDA. If you want to use the CUDA features, you need to customize the native bindings yourself.` [source](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp#requirements)

There are, however, implementations of `OpenCvSharp.Cuda.GpuMat` from the old version 2, a quick [search](https://github.com/search?q=OpenCvSharp.Cuda.GpuMat&type=Code) on GitHub may help you.

Comment: your link seems to be dead, could you find an alternative source? Usually it's helpful to add a quote in your answer incase the link dies in the future. Ta.

Comment: For anyone else coming this route, there's a link to that quote: https://discoverdot.net/projects/opencvsharp